# What options exist for adding three seats with 3 point seatbelts to a MWB Ford Transit?

Tags: ford, van, seat-belt, transit, campervan

**Vehicle**

2006 MWB Ford Transit 280 with dual sliding doors panel van

**Context**

A campervan conversion with fixed double bed, small sink and hob combo.  Insulated with recycled plastic throughout.  The fixed double bed is from the rear of the sliding doors to the rear doors.  Hob/ sink combo covers the driver side sliding door.

**Problem**

Would like to install 2, or ideally 3, seats with 3 point seat belts suitable for children under 10 years old but maintain a sleeping solution also.  The do not need to seat adults, only children.

**Caveats**

Must comply with UK legislation and MOT requirements

**Notes**

If it cannot be done safely I am comfortable with that answer and willing to simply scrap the idea and up[grade to a better family camper vehicle if required.

Comment: Why not simply install either a Rock and Roll or a Rib bed.  Both of those are fully legal and come with seat belts.

Comment: Pictures or diagrams of the layout may be extremely useful here. Where exactly do you plan on putting everything or is that part up in the air depending on what you're able to install. A seat with three point harnesses can easily be achieved. Not knowing exactly what else (you described what you want but didn't give dimensions) you are throwing into the mix leaves me at a quandary.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will come back with some diagrams and dimensions in the next 24 hours.  @Chenmunka; I can install a R&R but crash-tested to EU pull standards are upwards of £3500 which is half of the cost of the van.  For that money I would rather purchase a Mazda Bongo with comfortable seats already installed.